# Change the Text value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to make it so when a certain condition is met, the Text value will change to "You Win" rather than keep counting the value. SO if they go above 100 points or is equal to it, then it will print you win.

Tried comparing String and Text, as well as String and String with string.Compare.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public int score;

    private Board board;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        board = FindObjectOfType<Board>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
    public void IncreaseScore(int increase)
    {
        score += increase;
    }


}
```

Comment: Nvm Friends I just figured it out and I feel dumb.

Comment: delete the questions - it is as if nobody ever saw it ...

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = (score < 100) ? score.ToString() : "You Win";
}
```

Comment: you should add `if(scrore >= 100) enabled = false;` because it makes no sense to keep the `Update` running ;)